# Display time stamp in django templates?

Tags: python, django

I am using edit profile case in my Django templates and I am not sure how to convert a timestamp into proper time?

The value I am getting from API is "dob": 730166400000,.

Now I was using this in templates:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label text_left">Dob/label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="Graduation Year"
               value="{{ result_data_for_editing.dob |date:"U" }}" 
               name="graduationYear" id="graduationYear">
    </div>
</div>
```

but it shows invalid filter tag error. Is there any method I can convert a timestamp in Django templates only? I know it is possible in views, but I want to convert it in Django templates.

Comment: Please define "proper time". What is the format of "proper time"? Can you also extend your code example? Is it the attribute `value` of an HTML tag? Which one?

Comment: proper time means dd-mm-yyyy and yes extending the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use custom template filters

```
{{ datevalue| print_timestamp | date:"d-m-Y" }}

from django import template
import datetime
register = template.Library()

def print_timestamp(timestamp):
    try:
        ts = float(timestamp)
    except ValueError:
        return None
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)

register.filter(print_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

ok i misunderstood this, you should make template tag to make this work,make a folder with templatetags( or any name you want ) and create file named tags.py ( replace with your name, do not forget to create **init**.py )

```
from django import template    
register = template.Library()    

@register.filter('timestamp_to_time')
def timestamp_to_time(timestamp):
    import datetime
    return datetime.date.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp))
```

And then, include this in your template with

```
{%  load tags %}
```

and then

```
{{ result_data_for_editing.dob|timestamp_to_time|date:"d-m-Y" }}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't going to work. The `datevalue` should be a `datetime` object, but the OP has a `timestamp` in miliseconds since the UNIX epoch.

Comment: @cezar thanks for the corrections, i edited my answer